# Deploy J2EE app (running on JBoss) to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a J2EE web application running on JBoss and RHEL/CentOS.

What would be the best option available in AWS to migrate my application to cloud?

**Option 1:** Provision EC2 instance with RHEL/CentOS and deploy JBoss and deploy application war files.

**Option 2:** Deploy application into Elastic Beanstalk using Docker.

**Option 3:** Deploy application into Elastic Beanstalk using Java.

Option 3 does not suite me as they only support Tomcat.

Option 2 may suite me if I make code changes to deploy into Docker container.

Option 1 may suite me the best, but it may not be possible to auto-scale.

Kindly advice me if my understanding is correct or not and if you have any better ideas for running J2EE application using JBoss in AWS.

Much appreciated. Thanks in advance.